# Select multiple span elements with same class name

Tags: javascript

I have multiple span elements with same classname and I want to select all of them and display text in each of them. The problem is that a do not see anything and I am sure problem is how I select the elements.

JavaScript

```
let everyHeaderUsername = document.getElementsByClassName("user-header-username");
  for (let i = 0; i < everyHeaderUsername.length; ++i) {
    everyHeaderUsername[i].textContent = `Hi ${user.displayName}`;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="user-sign-in">Hi, <span class="user-header-username"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

your code is fine.  you don't define the variables you want to set text to:

```js
var user={displayName:'bob'};

let everyHeaderUsername = document.getElementsByClassName("user-header-username");
  for (let i = 0; i < everyHeaderUsername.length; ++i) {
    everyHeaderUsername[i].textContent = `${user.displayName}`;
}
```

```html
<div class="user-sign-in">Hi, <span class="user-header-username"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `innerText` instead of `textContent`. This is the result:

```
everyHeaderUsername[i].innerText = Hi ${user.displayName};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an object user with key **displayName**, that's your problem. Check this out:

```
let everyHeaderUsername = document.getElementsByClassName("user-header-username");
var user = {
    displayName : 'Nick'
}
  for (let i = 0; i < everyHeaderUsername.length; ++i) {
    everyHeaderUsername[i].textContent = `Hi ${user.displayName}`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern ES6 JS: Use [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which returns an array of elements and array map.

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('user-header-username');
elements.map(el => el.textContent = `Hello, ${user}!`);
```